# Using AudioBufferList with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, casting, swift

I have a bridging function in Swift, one of whose arguments in C is `AudioBufferList *`.  In Swift this generates an `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>`.  I've manage to deference the pointer  by calling `audioData[0]` (is there a better way?).  But I'm struggling with the next 2 tiers down: the `.mBuffers` array of `AudioBuffer`'s and their `void *` / `UnsafePointer<()>` `.mData` members.

In C it would simply be

```
Float32 *audioData = (Float 32*)abl->mBuffers[0]->mData;
output = audioData[sampleNum]...
```

In Swift the first odd thing is that it won't let me access the elements of `mBuffers` but is perfectly happy when I access it as a property.  In other words, this works and even has correct data (for the first member of `mBuffers` I presume)...

```
println(abl[0].mBuffers.mNumberChannels)  // But .mBuffers should be an []!
```

Second, it let's me print out `.mData` subscripts but the value is always `()`

```
println(abl[0].mBuffers.mData[10])  // Prints '()'
```

I've tried various casting ops and accessing with multiple indices but to no avail...any ideas?

Here are the C and Swift definitions for `AudioBufferList` and `AudioBuffer` for convenience...

```
// C
struct AudioBufferList
{
    UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
    AudioBuffer mBuffers[1]; // this is a variable length array of mNumberBuffers elements
    // ...and a bit more for c++
}


struct AudioBuffer
{
    UInt32  mNumberChannels;
    UInt32  mDataByteSize;
    void*   mData;
};
```

...

```
// SWIFT

struct AudioBufferList {
    var mNumberBuffers: UInt32
    var mBuffers: (AudioBuffer)
}

struct AudioBuffer {
    var mNumberChannels: UInt32
    var mDataByteSize: UInt32
    var mData: UnsafePointer<()>
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** Adam Ritenauer's answer is probably the best one now. To expand on it, you can look at the new utility functions/types in [the iOS 8.3 Core Audio changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/modules/CoreAudio.html).

`UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer` can be used to read/access some given data:

```
struct UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer {
    init(_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>)
    var count: Int
    subscript (index: Int) -> AudioBuffer { get nonmutating set }
}
```

And you can use the extensions on AudioBuffer & AudioBufferList to allocate your own:

```
extension AudioBufferList {
    static func sizeInBytes(maximumBuffers maximumBuffers: Int) -> Int
    static func allocate(maximumBuffers maximumBuffers: Int) -> UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer
}

extension AudioBuffer {
    init<Element>(_ typedBuffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>, numberOfChannels: Int)
}
```

---

<sub>Old answer:</sub>

This is a bit tricky because `AudioBufferList` is actually a variable-size struct. This means it's declared as having a single `AudioBuffer`, but really it has as many as specified by the `mNumberBuffers` member. This notion doesn't translate very well to Swift, which is why you see `var mBuffers: (AudioBuffer)`.

So the canonical way to access these buffers, and their data, would be using `UnsafeArray`. The code below provides some ideas, but `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeArray` aren't well documented, so this could be wrong.

```
// ***WARNING: UNTESTED CODE AHEAD***

let foo: UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList> // from elsewhere...

// This looks intuitive, but accessing `foo.memory` may be doing a copy.
let bufs = UnsafeArray<AudioBuffer>(start: &foo.memory.mBuffers, length: Int(foo.memory.mNumberBuffers))

// This is another alternative that should work...
let bufsStart = UnsafePointer<AudioBuffer>(UnsafePointer<UInt32>(foo) + 1) // Offset to mBuffers member
let bufs = UnsafeArray<AudioBuffer>(start: bufsStart, length: Int(foo.memory.mNumberBuffers))

// Hopefully this isn't doing a copy, but it shouldn't be too much of a problem anyway.
let buf: AudioBuffer = bufs[0] // or you could use a for loop over bufs, etc.

typealias MySample = Float32
let numSamples = Int(buf.mDataByteSize / UInt32(sizeof(MySample)))
let samples = UnsafeArray<MySample>(start: UnsafePointer<MySample>(buf.mData), length: numSamples)

// Now use the samples array...
```

This seems to work in the playground but it's hard for me to test on real audio data. In particular, I'm not 100% sure that using `start: &foo.memory.mBuffers` will work as expected. (It returns a different pointer from the original, although the data seem to be there.) Give it a shot and report back!

Edit: to debug this, by the way, you can for example:

```
(lldb) p foo
(UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>) $R1 = (value = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000000100700740)
(lldb) expr -lc -- ((int*)0x0000000100700740)[0]
(int) $2 = 42
(lldb) expr -lc -- ((int*)0x0000000100700740)[1]
(int) $3 = 43
...
```

Comment: Hi, haven't had a chance to try this out in my project but just wanted to say quickly that `reinterpretCast` might help too...

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm not sure how to use it here. It's undocumented so I don't know if it acts on the same location in memory, copies things around, or what...

Comment: thx. decided to give you the credit even if Adam's is better :)

Answer (score 23):

I found this by accident. Oddly the type ahead was actually working with Swift when it suggested UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer. Which you can initialize with an UnsafeMutablePointer argument. This type is a MutableCollectionType and provides subscript and generator access to the contained Audio Buffers.

For example you can set an ABL to silence with the following code

```
func renderCallback(ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {

    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(ioData)

    for buffer in abl {

        memset(buffer.mData, 0, Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))
    }

    return noErr
}
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to be fairly new.

Comment: Question: I have an `UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>` but the UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer required a `UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>`. Do you know how to convert it?

Comment: Setting to silence is one thing, but producing a programmatically generated sound seems to be something entirely different. I'm generating a pure tone using a sine wave and cannot figure out the proper way to convert from the floating-point amplitude to the Int32 that memset requires. All I get is horrible crackles. Any ideas?

Comment: @Georg you want `UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: myImmutableAudoBufferList)`

Answer (score 1):

I've found this works OK. `abl` is an AudioBufferList created from loading a 16bit AIFF audio file.

```
let mBuffers=abl.memory.mBuffers

let data=UnsafePointer<Int16>(mBuffers.mData)
let dataArray=UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start:data, count: Int(mBuffers.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))

//checking resulting array
let count=dataArray.count //this matches the expected number of samples in my case
for i in 0..<count
{
    print(dataArray[i]) //values look OK in my case
    print(" ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Swift 1.2

```
        var ddata: NSData
        buf = AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: numberOfFrames * UInt32(sizeof(Float32)), mData: &ddata)
        var audioBuffers = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1, mBuffers: buf!)
```